# React Native Android: is it possible to set a static IP?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have a scenario where the phone will connect via ethernet cable to a LAN and may or may not be assiged an IP via DHCP. In the case where it won't have DHCP, I need to set an IP. I can't find any documentation on this. Is it possible to - I guess first ask the user for permission - and then set a static IP of the android device?

Comment: https://blog.telegeography.com/how-do-ip-addresses-work

Comment: @ZUNJAE Thank you, I know how IP addresses works. Updated the question.